# Insert serial COM message in to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, serial-port

I've got an Arduino setup that outputs messages via a serial port via USB. Nothing 'clever' needs to be done to filter or sort these messages.

I want to insert these messages (along with a datestamp) in to a MySQL database. What would be the best way to do this reliably? C++/PHP/etc?

Please supply a bit of info to point me in the right direction.

Comment: My main skill lies in PHP, however, these messages need to be put in to the database instantly. Is it possible to get PHP to run constantly in the background without the need for a cron/auto-refresh type thing?

Comment: PHP outside of a web environment is probably a bad idea. Python, Ruby or Perl would be a better fit, or even NodeJS if you're feeling adventuresome.

Comment: +1 for any language that can read the serial port and write to a database - I currently like python :)

Answer (score 0):

Any programming language you use, it should definitely have a interrupt function for the COM port

( like func get_COM implements com_listener)

You have to use that interrupt function and write to db.